# facebook developer test user get relationship status

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to retrieve the relationship_status of my test user in my facebook app.
The status is set to Single on the webpage, and can be accessed by public.

But the api call:
 me?fields=id,name,relationship_status

returns nothing for relationship_status

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just because something is public on Facebook.com doesn't mean you can access it using the API without permission

Comment: how can I then set the permissions?

Comment: You ask the user for user_relationships permission. As specified in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions